# Javascript: Run function on 'select' 'option' / How to stop setInterval(...);?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, intervals

I'm working on a hobby project to help me better my javascript skills, so please bear with me.
In short: What I'm trying to make a is a moveset metronome for super smash bros melee characters. I have some frame data for when to input a button, and will play a beep.mp3 sound at the respective frames.
So what I'd like for that is to use a dependent dropdown, which I finally got working after some googling/tinkering. The code for that looks like this:

```
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>

#category2 option{
    display:none;
}

#category2 option.label{
    display:block;
}

</style>

<body>

<form id="formname" name="formname" method="post" action="submitform.asp" >

    <select name="category1" id="category1">

        <option value="">Select Category1</option>
        <option value="fox">Fox</option>
        <option value="mario">Mario</option>
    </select>



    <select disabled="disabled" id="category2" name="category2">
        <option value>Select Category2</option>


            <!-- FOX: -->
        <option rel="fox">Select: </option>
        <option rel="fox" value="wavedash">Wavedash</option>
        <option rel="fox" value="waveshine">Waveshine</option>

            <!-- MARIO -->
        <option rel="mario">Select: </option>
        <option rel="mario" value="wavedash">Wavedash</option>
    </select>

</form>

</body>

<script>

$(function(){

    var $cat = $("#category1"),
        $subcat = $("#category2");

    $cat.on("change",function(){
        var _rel = $(this).val();
        $subcat.find("option").attr("style","");
        $subcat.val("");
        if(!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled",true);
        $subcat.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
        $subcat.prop("disabled",false);
    });

});

</script>

</html>
```

Then, I have a different piece of code where I wrote a function using setInterval to actually display the selected character's selected move. For example, I selected "Fox" in the option, and then I selected Fox' move "Waveshine", I would want it to run this code:

```
var sound1 = new Audio('beep.mp3'); 
var sound2 = new Audio('beep2.mp3'); 


    var sec = 0;
    var frame = 0;
    var slowDown = 5;

    setInterval( function(){
        frame = ++frame%60;
        document.getElementById("frames").innerHTML="Framecount: "+String(pad(frame));

        if(frame >= 0 && frame <= 4){
            sound1.loop = false;
            sound1.play();

            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=("⇑");
        } else {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="";
        }
        if(frame >= 4 && frame <= 14){
            if(frame == 4){
                sound2.play();
            }
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=("R+⇘");
        }

    }, (1000/60)*slowDown);


    function pad ( val ) { 
        return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; 
    }
```

But I can't figure out how to make it run this code once I've selected "Fox" and "Wavedash" in the option, and I also have no idea how to stop the setInterval if I would switch to, for example, "Mario" and "Wavedash".
So basically I'm trying to combine the two pieces of code that I have now to run a function on interval, when a certain character and a certain move is selected.
Sorry if this post is a bit unclear, please let me know if I should expand on something. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Could you put your code in a snippet?

Comment: To make the function run when an option is chosen, wire an event handler to the "change" event of the `select`. To cancel an interval you must first set a variable (let's say "timer") to the return value of the `setInterval`, like `var timer = setInterval(function....` and then use `clearInterval(timer)` where you want it to stop.

Comment: The best way to stop `setInterval` is not to use it in the first place. Use `setTimeout` instead, and have the timeout function re-trigger itself if it's still valid. That makes it really easy to control. `setInterval` is nothing like so easy to control.

Answer (score 2):

First you would need to put this code within a function:

```
function playSound() {
    var sound1 = new Audio('beep.mp3'); 
    var sound2 = new Audio('beep2.mp3'); 
    var sec = 0;
    var frame = 0;
    var slowDown = 5;

    setInterval( function(){
        frame = ++frame%60;
        document.getElementById("frames").innerHTML="Framecount: "+String(pad(frame));

        if(frame >= 0 && frame <= 4){
            sound1.loop = false;
            sound1.play();

            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=("⇑");
        } else {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="";
        }
        if(frame >= 4 && frame <= 14){
            if(frame == 4){
                sound2.play();
            }
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=("R+⇘");
        }

    }, (1000/60)*slowDown);
}
```

And then on your `$cat` and `$subcat` onchange events you can then invoke the `playSound` method.

```
$cat.on("change",function() {
   // Your code
   latestSoundInterval = playSound();
});
```

`setInterval` returns an integer, therefore it would be best to keep track of all the `setIntervals` you invoke when the category/subcategory is changed.

```
var soundInterval = setInterval() { .... }
```

You could use the above variable as the return type of the new `playSound` function.

Then to stop the interval you can use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) and pass it back the `soundInterval` variable.

```
var latestSoundInterval = playSound();

clearInterval(latestSoundInterval); // Stop the set interval function
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've been trying but I can't quite get it to work yet. I've wrapped my playSound function, and added the `latestSoundInterval = playSound();` to the `$cat.on("change",function(){ // bla bla });` code, but I'm not sure where to add the code to stop the interval?

Comment: @Pazzle - You can add it to the category/subcategory `onchange` event or even create a new button.